# I've tried everything to fix my border radius issue

Tags: css, border-radius

I have a image inside of another element. Both elements have the `border-raidus` property.

I've tried many things to get the property to work on the image. Works fine on parent.

I've tried bellow options and yet nothing:

- `overflow:hidden`
- `!important`
- `border-collaspe:seperate`
- `perspective:1px`

My code:

```
section {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 25px; /* works */
    height: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .95;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 150px auto;
}

section img {
    border-radius: 10px; /* does not work */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but is just not visible because you have used padding on the image.

**Solution 1:**
Add 35px to your border radius, so in your case **border-radius: 45px;**
to get an effective border radius of 10px.

**Solution 2:**
Set image padding to 0 and image margin to 35px.

Comment: Third solution: Put the padding on the parent

Comment: This solved my problem, but can you explain why this worked? I'm not too sure if I get it or not.

Comment: It's all about the css box model. Perhaps reading this article is a good start (consider to read the full article): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#use_browser_devtools_to_view_the_box_model